# Determine if object derives from collection type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to determine if a generic object type ("T") method type parameter is a collection type.  I would typically be sending T through as a Generic.List but it could be any collection type as this is used in a helper function.

Would I be best to test if it implements IEnumerable<T>?

If so, what would the code look like?

**Update 14:17 GMT+10 Possibly extending on a solution [here](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/03/determine-if-object-implements.html) (however only works for List<T>'s not IEnumerable<T>'s when it should if List derives ?)**

```
T currentObj;    
// works if currentObj is List<T>
currentObj.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)
// does not work if currentObj is List<T>
currentObj.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This will be the simplest check..

```
if(Obj is ICollection)
{
    //Derived from ICollection
}
else
{
    //Not Derived from ICollection
}
```

Comment: So simple. Thanks, using your idea even 'obj is IEnumerable' and 'obj is IList' is working.  I had tried 'obj is IEnumerable<T>', 'obj is IList<T>'.. interestingly though that did not work.  I have a thought though, T would be a collection.  So perhaps it's testing a list of a list somehow *shrug*.

Comment: @GONeale: Hey this worked for me.



List<int> _ints = new List<int>(10);

            if (_ints is IList<int>)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No");
            }

Comment: **WARNING!** If `obj is ICollection` is true, it **does not follow** that `obj` also implements `ICollection<T>` for any T. The interfaces `ICollection` and `ICollection<T>` are two separate interfaces.

Comment: so @Timwi, what would you suggest? i see no answers from you :-\

Comment: @Brad: I was merely pointing out a possible source of confusion in this answer; I wasn’t implying that it’s _wrong_, and it appeared to solve the OP’s case, so I let it be. But since you asked, I posted a possible solution that I would consider using, but whether it’s “better” obviously depends on the use-case.

Comment: @Timwi, cool. i also wasn't trying to troll, you just seemed to have another good idea we all weren't seeing. thanks for posting it!

Comment: it is really weird that almost all containers in Collections have implemented  `ICollection` except `Hashset` only implemented `ICollection<T>`...

Answer (score 17):

You can use Type.GetInterface() with the mangled name.

```
private bool IsTAnEnumerable<T>(T x)
{
    return null != typeof(T).GetInterface("IEnumerable`1");
}
```

Comment: Any reason for the null on the left side?

Comment: As opposed to on the right?  Old habits of a C programmer where a flubbed "if (i=0)" is an assignment within the conditional, not a compile error.

Answer (score 9):

In order to get the actual type of T at runtime, you can use the typeof(T) expression.  From there the normal type comparison operators will do the trick

```
bool isEnumerable = typeof(IEnumerable<int>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
```

Full Code Sample:

```
static bool Foo<T>()
{
  return typeof(IEnumerable<int>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
}

Foo<List<T>>();  // true
Foo<int>(); // false
```

Comment: What is the use of int, or was that what you meant by normal type comparison? My List would hold a custom object, but it could be anything as this is used in a Helper function. PS. I tested this code and unfortunately it returned false using int or T.

Comment: @GONeale, int is just a place holder for the sample code.  I verified this code works on my machine when T is List<T> on my machine

Comment: Hmm. I am using Intermediate Window now and typeof(IEnumerable<int>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)) is returning false.  For ref. T = System.Collections.Generic.List<WcfClientModuleMessageHistory>

Comment: @GONeal, The immediate window is very different than compiling and running the code.  Especially with regards to generics

Comment: @Jared, thanks but still no luck. Maybe I should post a complete code sample of what I am trying to do: http://bit.ly/2Bt2jI

Comment: Thanks for your help Jared.  I accepted s_ruchit's answer, I have no idea why yours didn't work, when it clearly looks like it should.  Just didn't work with my custom generic list of objects.

Comment: @GONeal, no worries.  You should accept whatever answer helps you the most.

Answer (score 9):

Personally I tend to use a method that I wrote myself, called `TryGetInterfaceGenericParameters`, which I posted below. Here is how to use it in your case:

### Example of use

```cs
object currentObj = ...;  // get the object
Type[] typeArguments;
if (currentObj.GetType().TryGetInterfaceGenericParameters(typeof(IEnumerable<>), out typeArguments))
{
    var innerType = typeArguments[0];
    // currentObj implements IEnumerable<innerType>
}
else
{
    // The type does not implement IEnumerable<T> for any T
}
```

It is important to note here that you pass in `typeof(IEnumerable<>)`, **not** `typeof(IEnumerable)` (which is an entirely different type) and also **not** `typeof(IEnumerable<T>)` for any `T` (if you already know the `T`, you don’t need this method). Of course this works with any generic interface, e.g. you can use `typeof(IDictionary<,>)` as well (but **not** `typeof(IDictionary)`).

### Method source

```cs
/// <summary>
///     Determines whether the current type is or implements the specified generic interface, and determines that
///     interface's generic type parameters.</summary>
/// <param name="type">
///     The current type.</param>
/// <param name="interface">
///     A generic type definition for an interface, e.g. typeof(ICollection&lt;&gt;) or typeof(IDictionary&lt;,&gt;).</param>
/// <param name="typeParameters">
///     Will receive an array containing the generic type parameters of the interface.</param>
/// <returns>
///     True if the current type is or implements the specified generic interface.</returns>
public static bool TryGetInterfaceGenericParameters(this Type type, Type @interface, out Type[] typeParameters)
{
    typeParameters = null;

    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == @interface)
    {
        typeParameters = type.GetGenericArguments();
        return true;
    }

    var implements = type.FindInterfaces((ty, obj) => ty.IsGenericType && ty.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == @interface, null).FirstOrDefault();
    if (implements == null)
        return false;

    typeParameters = implements.GetGenericArguments();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would test `IEnumerable` instead, since a collection type could implement only `IEnumerable`, it doesn't have to implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

It also depends: what do you mean with *collection type*? You could have a collection without implementing any of those interfaces.

Comment: Well any object which can hold a list of objects.  I'd truly only be using List<T> but a generic handler would have been nicer.

Comment: The most common types (`List`, array and `Dictionary`) all implement `IEnumerable` but with discrepancies in `IEnumerable<T>` (the `T` in a dictionary is `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`). Simply checking for `IEnumerable` is thus easier and still correct.

Answer (score 3):

Also, remember just because you are using generics, don't forget other basic techniques, in this case, like overloading.   I suspect the you are planning something like this:

```
void SomeFunc<T>(T t)
{
    if (IsCollectionCase(t))
       DoSomethingForCollections()
    else
       DoSOmethingElse();
}
```

This would be far better handled as:

```
void SomeFunc(IEnumerable t)
{
       DoSomethingForCollections()
}
void SomeFunc<T>(T t)
{
       DoSomethingElse()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments James, yep normally I would and an overload would do the trick, but only doing some simple collection adding and private variable changes if it is a list, so no need for any additional function calls.  Cheers.

Comment: This will not work! For example a List<int> will satisfy both overrides so the compiler doesn't know which one to choose. At least for .Net Core / Roslyn, it chooses the second override.

Answer (score 2):

While I can't be certain what the original poster's intent was, there have been several responses to the effect of casting to IEnumerable for testing.  That's fine, but everyone should be aware that string instances pass this test, which may not be something the original author intended.  I know I certainly didn't when I went looking for an answer and found this post:

```
string testString = "Test";
Console.WriteLine(testString as IEnumerable != null);  // returns true
```

I am in the process of trying to write a custom serializer that uses reflection to accomplish certain tasks.  As part of a task, I need to determine if a property value is a collection/array/list of items or a single property value.  What is particularly annoying is that several Linq expressions actually result in an enumerable type value, but GetType().IsArray returns false for these, and casting them to ICollection returns null as well, but casting them to IEnumerable returns a non-null value.

So...for the time being, I am still seeking a solution that works for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity and code sharing, I usually use this extension method:

```
public static bool IsGenericList(this object obj)
{
    return IsGenericList(obj.GetType());
}

public static bool IsGenericList(this Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
    }

    foreach (Type @interface in type.GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (@interface.IsGenericType)
        {
            if (@interface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
            {
                // if needed, you can also return the type used as generic argument
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return (type.GetInterface("IEnumerable") != null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a check and get true for any list/collection/IEnumerable, but get false for type of string, then

```
   private static bool IsIEnumerable(Type requestType)
   {
      var isIEnumerable = typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(requestType);
      var notString = !typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(requestType);
      return isIEnumerable && notString;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I love generics. In this method `T` must have a public and parameterless constructor which means you can not use `IList<object>` for `T`. You must use `List<object>`

```
public static T IsEnumerable<T>() where T : new() {
    if (new T() is IEnumerable) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue while attempting to serialize any object to JSON format.  Here is what I ended up using:

```
Type typ = value.GetType();

// Check for array type
if(typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typ) || typeof(IEnumerable<>).IsAssignableFrom(typ))
{ 
    List<object> list = ((IEnumerable)value).Cast<object>().ToList();
    //Serialize as an array with each item in the list...
}
else
{
    //Serialize as object or value type...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an ICollection of any type (List or HashSet for example):

```
internal static bool IsCollection(this Type type) => type.GetGenericArguments().Length > 0 && (typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(type.GetGenericArguments()[0])).IsAssignableFrom(type);
```