# How to know a given variable is a collection rather than a simple item in C#?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have this method:

```
public void DoSomething(object parameter)
```

Since it accepts `object` as input, arrays and lists and `IEnumerable<T>` can be passed to it.

I want to check the type and make sure that it's a single object, not a collection of objects.

I can check each collection possibility separately, but is there a neat better way to check it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190204/check-if-object-is-dictionary-or-list

Comment: @MaythamFahmi, the accepted answer does not take arrays into consideration. That's why I asked for it. There should be a neat way to see if a parameter is made of more than one item.

Comment: Why though? It's better to force the caller to be specific, and call different methods for each case.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, that's true. It might be a bad design. But still I want to know if a given parameter is a single object, or anything more than a single one.

Comment: You could check if the object implements `IEnumerable`. But beware that also `string` does it.

Comment: Let's compare to JS. In JavaScript we only have one collection type, `[]` and we can check the presence of `.length` to check if it's a collection or a single object. @KlausGütter, does that also include arrays?

Comment: "does that also include arrays" - yes, arrays implement `IEnumerable` otherwise foreach would not work on them.

Comment: Some clarifications would help someone to write code for you: do you consider arrays of *value type* (`int[10]`) as "a collection of objects"? Is `string` "a collection of char" or "single object"? Do you consider type with an indexer, but not derived from of IList/IEnumerable/ICollection as "a collection of object" (due to ability to say `parameter[1]`) or "a single object" (since it is not derived from the interface you like) - I think based on your comment about JavaScript the answer is "single", but it good to write explicitly (`var a={}; a[1]="test"` is valid JavaScript)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750039/determine-if-object-derives-from-collection-type This question has some pretty well-explanatory and extended answers on this.

Comment: Bear in mind that there is nothing stopping anyone from constructing a new type that, logically, represents a collection of objects whilst supporting none of the conventional interfaces that most standard collections implement. There's nothing "inherent" about a collection that is necessarily detectable. It seems strange, therefore, that your code somehow always works correctly for objects but cannot for collections.

Comment: Why you need this . for what ? Can you show some context for this?

Answer (score 3):

The comments already reference this, but you could check if the item is an ICollection or IEnumerable.

```
if(parameter is IEnumerable enumerable)
{
 // You can access the non-generic list with enumerable
}
```

Note that a string also implements this. So if you don't want that specific type, you could add `and is not string` to the statement. But also keep in mind, you can create your own types that implement IEnumerable and then it would also ne accepted.

I see you reference javascript in the comments. Javascript, AFAIK, only has an array type. C# has multiple "list" types, and a big part of that is IEnumerable, which allows you to enumerate a list of items. It doesn't matter if that is a list, queue, stack, array, etc..

You could also check for `ICollection`, or something like `ICollection<object>` or `IEnumerable<object>`.

I am mostly repeating the answers from the linked answer from the comment: [Check if Object is Dictionary or List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190204/check-if-object-is-dictionary-or-list)

It is a bad practice to do this, though. I feel like this is an https://xyproblem.info/ ; it would be better to explain to us WHY you are doing this, perhaps we can solve the problem that is causing you to need this code.

If this answer doesn't help you, please explain why so we can be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Because :

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

List and Array all implement `IList<T>` and `IList<T>` also implement `IEnumerable`
So quikly answer is that only need check IEnumerable:

```
public void DoSomething(object parameter)
{
    if(parameter is not IEnumerable)
    {
         //here
    }
}
```

But it's like XY Problem I guess you want this ? but I don't really  know what you want.

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T parameter) where T : XXXClass
    {
         //to make soure parameter is implement XXXClass.
    }
```